# Where to start with WCF and wsdl file?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I need to create a service for a client to use/consume(I think consume is the right terminology).

I am a completely newbie to `WCF` and `web services`.

I have done most of the tutorials and understand a bit how everything works.

Now i have this wsdl file:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                  xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
                  xmlns:tns="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService" 
                  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
                  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                  targetNamespace="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
              targetNamespace="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService">
      <s:element name="ChangePassword">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="serviceProviderGuid" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="oldPassword" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="newPassword" type="s:string"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="ChangePasswordResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ChangePasswordResult">
              <s:complexType mixed="true">
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any/>
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacements">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="serviceProviderGuid" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsResult">
              <s:complexType mixed="true">
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any/>
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="ConfirmDownload">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="serviceProviderGuid" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="dateOfLatestRecordRecieved" type="s:dateTime"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="ConfirmDownloadResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ConfirmDownloadResult">
              <s:complexType mixed="true">
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any/>
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="serviceProviderGuid" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xml" type="s:string"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsResult">
              <s:complexType mixed="true">
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any/>
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ChangePasswordSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ChangePassword"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ChangePasswordSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ChangePasswordResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCampaignSchedulePlacements"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ConfirmDownloadSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConfirmDownload"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ConfirmDownloadSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConfirmDownloadResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ShopriteIntegrationTestoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="ChangePassword">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ChangePasswordSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ChangePasswordSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacements">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConfirmDownload">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ConfirmDownloadSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ConfirmDownloadSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ShopriteIntegrationTestoap" type="tns:ShopriteIntegrationTestoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ChangePassword">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/ChangePassword" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacements">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/GetCampaignSchedulePlacements" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConfirmDownload">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/ConfirmDownload" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="ShopriteIntegrationServiceSoap12" type="tns:ShopriteIntegrationServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ChangePassword">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/ChangePassword" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCampaignSchedulePlacements">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/GetCampaignSchedulePlacements" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ConfirmDownload">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/ConfirmDownload" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://196.37.139.18/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService/UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ShopriteIntegrationService">
    <wsdl:port name="ShopriteIntegrationServiceSoap" binding="tns:ShopriteIntegrationTestoap">
      <soap:address location="http://jhbweb01/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ShopriteIntegrationServiceSoap12" binding="tns:ShopriteIntegrationServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://jhbweb01/IntegrationTest/ShopriteIntegrationService.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This is what i got so for:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IShopriteService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ChangePassword(string serviceProviderGuid, string oldPassword, DateTime newPassword);

    [OperationContract]
    string ChangePasswordResponse();

    [OperationContract]
    void GetCampaignSchedulePlacements(string serviceProviderGuid, string password);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse();

    [OperationContract]
    void ConfirmDownload(string serviceProviderGuid, string password, DateTime dateOfLatestRecordRecieved);

    [OperationContract]
    string ConfirmDownloadResponse();

    [OperationContract]
    void UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements(string serviceProviderGuid, string password, string xml);

    [OperationContract]
    string UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse();
}
```

Implemented methods:

```
public class ShopriteService : IShopriteService
    {
    public void ChangePassword(string serviceProviderGuid, string oldPassword, DateTime newPassword)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ChangePasswordResponse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetCampaignSchedulePlacements(string serviceProviderGuid, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ConfirmDownload(string serviceProviderGuid, string password, DateTime dateOfLatestRecordRecieved)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ConfirmDownloadResponse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UploadCampaignSchedulePlacements(string serviceProviderGuid, string password, string xml)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string UploadCampaignSchedulePlacementsResponse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have no idea if i am even on the right track...

Explain a bit, what is going on in the `wsdl` file.

Where do i go from here?

Is there a certain structure i can use?  (like the `MVVM` structure)

Comment: What do you mean by where do i go from here? What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @Rajesh I need to create a service for a client to use/consume(I think consume is the right terminology).

Comment: Looks like you have implemented the service defined in the wsdl, not a client to consume it.

Comment: @BenRobinson Ben, so what should i be doing? Then i am completely on the wrong track...

Comment: Looks fine, start filling out the method implementations.

Comment: You need to implement the methods in the ShopriteService class for the expected behaviour that needs to be performed when invoked by a client. Once this is done just host your WCF service? Then you can perform add service reference on your client to invoke these service methods

Comment: The WCF side of things is basically done. The next step is to remove all the NotImplementedExceptions and actually do the work :)

Comment: Also you dont need a seperate method for response on each method. Just have one method and set its return type to what is expected to be returned to the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WSDL is nothing more than a description of your service and it allow clients to consume it as a web service. 
So: the wsdl reflects your interface -> your interface is implemented by a class. Last step will be to write the logic for your interface methods (ie: the ChangePassword method).
Also, I got the impression something is wrong in the ServiceContract, let's take the ChangePassword method for instance: 
Because the method will return a string you can just define the following :

```
[OperationContract]
string ChangePassword(string serviceProviderGuid, string oldPassword, DateTime newPassword);
```

instead of

```
[OperationContract]
void ChangePassword(string serviceProviderGuid, string oldPassword, DateTime newPassword);

[OperationContract]
string ChangePasswordResponse();
```

So basically think of your WCF (or Ws) as a traditional class library. It only allows to be called and referenced over [HTTP/SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_services_protocol_stack)

Comment: Thanks for the response Giorgio. The reason why i have added the 
`[OperationContract]
string ChangePasswordResponse();`
method was because it was in the wsdl file... 

Can i assume that i don't need all the methods in the wsdl file and combine some of the methods like you stated in your answer? 

Would me combining the methods not break the clients code? Would they not be looking for all those methods?

Comment: Hi Willem, well the wsdl is the result of the publish of your service, so you're in control! Feel free to change it as you prefer right now that you're in the development phase, the clients code will need to be changed in order to reflect the changes in the WSDL, but I guess this should not be an issue until the ws is not fully implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the articlesthat shows on how to create your WCF service and consume it with a client application:

1. [Create and consume WCF service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service)
2. [Consume a WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
3. [Hosting and consuming WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx)
4. [Video to create and consume WCF Service](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjBNEEHfKFQ)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are on your way! You can use any design pattern you like the solves the problem at hand. I normally set up my service layer to be as thin as possible and simply abstract away the underlying logic through an interface of some sort, most often a Façade which isn't to say that is the correct thing in your case.

As to the WSDL, it's essentially defining your service by describing a set of abstractions relating to the types and endpoints your service exposes. You can read more details over at [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl). Through the WSDL clients can obtain information about your service needed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XML spy to understand the how WSDL mapped to WCF services and XSDs are mapped to Data Contract 
http://www.altova.com/simpledownload2c.html?gclid=CJeFgKGEr64CFSgntAod9m4oSA